# PayPal Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Buttons') in svelte

Tags: paypal, svelte, sveltekit

I want to add PayPal button in my svelte kit app, but when I test it say that `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Buttons')`  and I try to figure out how to solve this I found that it somewhere needs to asynchronized the function, but I couldn't solve it at the end.

this is the code from `+page.svelte` in the **script tag**:

```js
import { loadScript } from '@paypal/paypal-js';

let amount = 50;

    const CLIENT_ID = import.meta.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_API;

    loadScript({ 'client-id': CLIENT_ID }).then((paypal) => {
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                color: 'blue',
                shape: 'pill'
            },
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                // Set up the transaction
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [
                        {
                            amount: {
                                value: amount
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: async function (data, actions) {
                // Capture order after payment approved
                const details = await actions.order.capture();
                alert('Payment successful!');
            },
            onError: function (err) {
                // Log error if something goes wrong during approval
                alert('Something went wrong');
                console.log('Something went wrong', err);
            }
        }).render("#paypal-button-container");
    });
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js#query-parameters), the parameter should be `clientId` when used in the script. Maybe that messes things up? Also, environment variables are usually imported from the [`$env` modules](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. They need to fix it in their [svelte-paypal-js](https://github.com/paypal-examples/svelte-paypal-js) repo, I don't understand why they published it without testing.

Just wrap it with `onMount()` (for svelte 4.0.5)

```
    onMount(() => {
      loadScript({ 'client-id': CLIENT_ID }).then((paypal) => {
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                color: 'blue',
                shape: 'pill'
            },
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                // Set up the transaction
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [
                        {
                            amount: {
                                value: amount
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: async function (data, actions) {
                // Capture order after payment approved
                const details = await actions.order.capture();
                alert('Payment successful!');
            },
            onError: function (err) {
                // Log error if something goes wrong during approval
                alert('Something went wrong');
                console.log('Something went wrong', err);
            }
        }).render("#paypal-button-container");
    });
   });
```

This happens because code in svelte run both on server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Check for paypal and Button objects before using them.

```
onMount(() => {
    loadScript({ clientId: PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, vault: true }).then((paypal) => {
        if (
            paypal === undefined ||
            paypal === null ||
            paypal.Buttons === undefined ||
            paypal.Buttons === null
        ) {
            return;
        }

        paypal
            .Buttons({ ... })
            .render('#paypal-button-container');
    });
});
```